# How to solve app:kaptDebugKotlin error when using Dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying Dagger 2 for the first time using tutorial. When I start application on some stage there appears an error I can't resolve:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

The code is extremely simple but I have no idea what is wrong there. There is `MainActivity` class with default code and some additional classes

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt:

```
import dagger.Component
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides

@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun computer(): Computer
}

@Module
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideComputer(
        processor: Processor, ram: RAM, motherboard: Motherboard
    ): Computer {
        return Computer(processor, ram, motherboard)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideProcessor() = Processor()

    @Provides
    fun provideRam(): RAM = RAM()

    @Provides
    fun provideMotherboard(): Motherboard = Motherboard()
}
```

Computer.kt file with other small classes:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

data class Computer @Inject constructor(
    val processor: Processor,
    val ram: RAM,
    val motherboard: Motherboard
)

class Processor @Inject constructor() {
    override fun toString() = "AB2022"
}
class RAM  @Inject constructor() {
    override fun toString() = "16GB"
}

class Motherboard @Inject constructor() {
    override fun toString() = "X7 3000"
}
```

App gradle dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daggertutorial"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.36'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.36'


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

code on github: `https://github.com/faritowich/DaggerTutorial`

Comment: Do you set your Application class to use dagger?

Comment: What do you mean? How to set it?

Comment: You nees to override the Application class. See https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android